# pmd high CPU usage

Tags: 20.04, cpu, cpu-load

For a couple of days my laptop has been consuming a lot more power than before, noticeable by how fast the battery runs out when not plugged. This is matched by periodic (~20-30s) fan noise spikes typical of high CPU usage. This happens even when I close all applications.
I've installed `atop` to try and find out which process is causing this:

```
    PID     TID S  CPU COMMAND-LINE (horizontal scroll with <- and -> keys)                                                              1/65
 351173       - E  50% pmd
 350924       - E  50% pmd
 350675       - E  11% /opt/traps/bin/pmd
 152048       - S   3% /snap/firefox/2277/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 33176 -prefMapSize 244985 -
```

Varying slightly over time, always with `pmd` on top. What does this mean? What's `pmd`? How can I solve it?

I *think* that the problems started after the latest software upgrades that I installed. I have Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Comment: 'which pmd' might give you the process location.
'lsof | grep pmd' might give you  disk activity
'pmd --help' or 'man pmd'
or 'sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof pmd)' might tame it a bit.

or chase up the parent process if any  https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-find-the-parent-process-id-with-bash/